# View box in High chart

Tags: css, highcharts

```
chart: {
      height:"300",
      width:"600",              
      type: 'column',
      viewBox:"0 0 1000 400" 
   }
```

The `viewbox` is there is not working in high chart.

Kindly give me a solution.

Comment: Viewbox is not available in Highcharts. All paramters are available here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

Comment: @jem: You should accept helpful answers. It helps in building your repo as well SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `viewBox` with Highcharts.

Refer: [API Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart)

To create border around chart you can use:

```
chart: {
      height:"300",
      width:"600",              
      type: 'column',
      borderWidth:1, // around chart
      plotBorderWidth:1, // around plot
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the chart is appended to the DOM. It is an SVG Node element on which you can set attribute like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var highchart = document.querySelector(".highcharts-container svg:last-of-type");
    highchart.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 1324 400");
}, 10);
```

The timeout is to ensure highcharts had time to insert the graph in the DOM. The data populating itself happens after initialisation so 10ms is fine.